# String with different charcters to integer Array

Tags: java, string

How to convert a String that contains random characters into a meaningful Integer Array ?

`int MAX= 27;`

I have string `input="-3,5,7-12,20-16,21-";`

How do I convert this into an Integer array like `[1,2,3,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,20,19,18,17,16,21,22,23... MAX ]`

**(WITHOUT USING ANY INBUILT FUNCTIONS like input.split(","))**

```
package Others;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class convertToInteger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numbers = "-3,5,7-12,20-16,21-";
        char c[] = numbers.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(c.length);
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            // System.out.println(!(c[i] == '3') + "" + c[i]);

            if (numbers.charAt(i) == '-' || numbers.charAt(i) == ',') {

            }
            else {
                int temp = c[i];
                int actual = (int) c[i];

                if (temp == actual) {
                    System.out.println("Integer" + c[i]);
                    if (!((c[i + 1]) == ',')) {

                    }
                }
                // System.out.println(c[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: `substring()` allowed or nothing but loops?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

1. you use a `StringBuilder` and add characters to it till you encounter the character ','.
2. And when you encounter ',' use `Integer.parseInt` function using the string got from the `StringBuilder` to get the int to be stored in the `ArrayList`. Use `try - catch` for `NumberFormatException`. If any exception is caught call a function say `evaluateExpression` and pass the string as parameter and return the evaluated integer to store in the `ArrayList`.
3. Declare a function say `evaluateExpression` having `String` as parameter and `int` as return value.
4. In the function `evaluateExpression` split the parameter to `char` array and search for non numeric values while creating String of integers using `StringBuilders` and create `Integers` as mentioned above. Also determine the type of operator. Now you evaluate the expression using the operator and return the evaluated value.
5. Finally sort the `ArrayList` and recover the array of `Integer` from this `ArrayList`

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: What about 7-12 and 21- and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you don't get a `,` or a `-` add it to your number, Once you get it that's the seperation. So Check if it is less than `MAX` and then add it to your list.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Demo1 {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        String input = "-3,5,7-12,200-16,21-";
        int MAX = 20;
        int num = 0;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        char []notAllowed = {',', '-', ' '};

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char ch = input.charAt(i) ;
            if(isAllowed(notAllowed, ch)) {
                num = num * 10 + ch - 48;           
            }
            else {
                if(num <= MAX) {
                    list.add(num);
                }
                num = 0;
            }
            if(isAllowed(notAllowed, ch) && i == input.length() - 1) {
                list.add(num);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        //if you want to sort it
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static boolean isAllowed(char[] notAllowed, char ch) {
        for(int i = 0; i < notAllowed.length; i++)
            if(ch == notAllowed[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question correctly, you can do something like follow

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    private static final String NUMBER_ONLY_REGEX = "\\d+";

    private static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("(,|-)");

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String numbers = "-3,5,7-12,20-16,21-";
        final String[] matcher = REGEX.split(numbers);
        final List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < matcher.length; i++) {
            if(matcher[i].matches(NUMBER_ONLY_REGEX)) {
                integerList.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher[i].trim()));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(integerList);
    }
}
```